# Trying to Create CSV File from with Data from Another CSV File

Tags: python, python-2.7, csv, datetime

I'm teaching myself Python 2.7 and I'm having a really hard time with this code! I'm trying to extract data from a CSV file and write into another CSV file. Here is what I have done so far. Rows 1 and 2 are dates (YYYY/MM/DD) and I'm trying to get row 3 to be the difference between the 2 dates. Does anyone know how to do this? It gives me a `"IOERROR: File not open for reading"` for `"print row[0] in n"`. How do I do this please?! Any help would be suuuuper welcome! 
Thank you!

```
Import CSV
n = open("newfile.csv", 'w')

with open("TestWorkbook3.csv", 'r') as o:
    reader = csv.reader(o, delimiter=",")
    for row in reader:
        print row[0] in n
        print row[1] in n
        print row[2] in n
        print difference in n

from datetime import date   
difference = timedelta.days(row[2]-row[1])
```

Comment: You should open `newfile.csv` in read mode: `n = open("newfile.csv")` and read out content from it using `read`

Comment: You should use a csv writer to write the csv file. 'print in n' is not a way to write to a file. Also, do you mean row or column?

Comment: Column! How do I write to a file then? Can you please help?

Comment: Just check the docs, you already figured out how to read, it's almost identical, there are examples.